# SQL / Celonis - where field only contains just numeric, remove anything else

Tags: sql, sql-server, numeric

In a field I want to keep those where it is only a number between 100000 and 999999

This field has a mixture of numeric, alphanumeric, alphabet characters.

This function will keep if there is a number in a field e.g. keep abc123 where I would want that removed

```
where some_column NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

**Additional - Celonis Equivalent ?**

Gordon has kindly provided SQL Server coding to do this exactly as intended.

I was hoping this would work in **Celonis** but the try_convert function is not supported. Is there another method?

```
where try_convert(int, some_column) between 100000 and 999999
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: SQL Server?  MySQL?  PostgreSQL?  DB2?  Oracle?  SQLite?  etc, etc?

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is good to know that Celonis uses Vertica SQL for its event collection. Vertica has some specific functions, that you can find at https://www.vertica.com/docs/.

That said, I'm not sure if I understand your question well, but I think that the [REGEXP_ILIKE](https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/RegularExpressions/REGEXP_ILIKE.htm?) is something you could use, where '[0-9]' could be the expression you are looking for to check if your field contains a numeric value.

If you want to extract the number itself (for instance to check if it is between 100000 and 999999, use then [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/RegularExpressions/REGEXP_SUBSTR.htm?).

Your code will be something like:
`WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(some_column, [0-9]) BETWEEN 100000 AND 999999`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax suggests you are using SQL Server.  If so, try:

```
where try_convert(int, some_column) between 100000 and 999999
```

Comment: Briliant Gordon, thanks for which works in SQL Server. Now I need a Celonis version of this function as try_convert is not supported.

Comment: @Rockshah . . . This question is tagged SQL Server and this code works in all supported versions of SQL Server.  If you have a different question (such as a different database), then ask a *new* question.